# How to upload files with angularjs and laravel 5.2?

Tags: angularjs, laravel, laravel-5

I want to upload an image to the server with angularjs

```
var fileInputElement = $('input[name=avatar]');
        var formData = new FormData();

        formData.append("team_name", $('input[name=team_name]').val());
        formData.append("associated_users", $('input[name=associated_users]').val()); // number 123456 is immediately converted to a string "123456"

// HTML file input, chosen by user
        formData.append("avatar", fileInputElement[0].files);
        $http.post('groups', formData)
            .then(
                function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    //$scope.teams.push(response.data)
                },
                function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                }
            );
```

but in my controller when i return the avatar like this:

```
 return "avatar =>" . Input::file('avatar');
```

the result is :

```
 data:"avatar =>"
```

i don't know what's wrong with this code?

Comment: covert the file to base64 format in angular part and decode it at laravel

Comment: check out this fiddle for encoding to base64 http://jsfiddle.net/eliseosoto/JHQnk/ also check to decode base64 data using php http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php

Comment: As a side note, you shouldn't be using the `Input::` class to get variables from the request in Laravel 5.2+, you should be injecting the request as a dependency to the first argument in your controller method, like this: `public function myFunc(Request $request, ....)`. Then like this: `$request->file('avatar');`

Comment: @Ohgodwhy i tried it and it gives me the same result

Comment: @MohammadAL-Raoosh Indeed. Simply a side note. The `Input::` class is deprecated in Laravel 5.2 and will be removed in future versions, just wanted to give you a heads up. :). Also, you can't return the `file` its self, as someone else mentioned above, use something like `base64_encode($request->file('avatar'))` when you return it, then decode that inside of an image, like `<img src="data:image/(jpeg/png/etc);charset=utf-8;base64,<STRING_FROM_SERVER>">`